# How to save canvas drawing using SurfaceView as image?

Tags: android

How to save canvas drawing using SurfaceView as image not the view.

Answer (score 2):

Try below code might help

```
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mSurfaceView.getWidth(), mSurfaceView.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
mSurfaceView.draw(new Canvas(bitmap));
try {
    OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(saved.png));
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.w(TAG, e);
}
```